# Adding new column using custom function in data frame using dplyr/data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm relatively new to R programing and am trying to figure out how to use custom functions to evaluate new columns of a data frame using `dplyr` or `data.table` in a memory efficient manner. Can someone please help

Here is a brief summary of my problem

Data frames 1 and 2 have the same type and number of columns

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C"), col2 = c(10,20,30))
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c("DA", "EE", "FB", "C"), col2 = c(10,20,30,40))
```

These data frames have millions of records.

Now I want to add a new column to one of the data frames (say df1) by using the values in df2.

```
library(dplyr)

calculateCol3 <- function(word) {
df2 %>%
    filter(grepl(paste0(word, "$"),col1) )%>%
    summarize(col3= sum(col2))
col3
}

df1 %>% group_by(col1) %>% mutate(col3 = calcualteCol3(col1))
```

This method works but it is painfully slow and I guess this is because of copying the data sets too many times. Can someone suggest a better way of doing the same? The expected result is:

```
col1 col2 col3
   A   10   10
   B   20   30
   C   30   40
```

I also tried converting the data frames to data.table as follows

```
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table(df2)

dt1[, col3 := calculateCol3(col1)}, by = 1:nrow(dt1)]
```

Everything seems to be slow. Am sure there is a better way to achieve this. Can someone help

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, as a general rule, you should try to write your function so that it doesn't need to be applied NROW separate times. (It's not clear to me what your function is supposed to do, so I can't help with anything more specific.)

Comment: Your example code doesn't work at all.

Comment: `df3 = grepl(paste0(word, '$'), df2$col1))` should be a binary `TRUE/FALSE` . How do you expect `df3$col2` to behave?

Comment: I have edited the function. I expect the result as follows

Comment: I have edited the function. I expect the result as follows 
head(df1)
col1 col2 col3
A    10    10
B     20    30
C     30    40

Comment: Maybe - `cbind(df1, col2=sapply(df1$col1, function(x) sum(df2$col2[grepl(paste0(x,"$"), df2$col1)])))` - I'm guessing a bit though? And that is probably not very fast - maybe you could look at the "fuzzyjoin" package too - https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin

Comment: How complex are the strings to be matched? If `col1` is as simple as your example, it does not make sense at all to look for a complex solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an efficient solution I would suggest you won't use regex and don't do by-row operations. If all your function is doing is to join by the last letter, you could just get that latter without using regex and then do a binary join using `data.table` (for efficiency)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, EndWith := substring(col1, nchar(as.character(col1)))]
setDT(df1)[df2, col3 := i.col2, on = .(col1 = EndWith)]
df1
#    col1 col2 col3
# 1:    A   10   10
# 2:    B   20   30
# 3:    C   30   40
```

Now, by looking at your function, it seems like you also trying to sum the values in `df2$col2` per join. No problem, you can run functions while doing a binary join in `data.table` too. Lets say this is your `df2` (just to illustrate when you have more than a single value per last letter)

```
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c("DA", "FA", "EE", "FB", "C", "fC"), col2 = c(10,20,10,30,40,30))
df2
#   col1 col2
# 1   DA   10
# 2   FA   20
# 3   EE   10
# 4   FB   30
# 5    C   40
# 6   fC   30
```

The first step is the same

```
setDT(df2)[, EndWith := substring(col1, nchar(as.character(col1)))]
```

While the second step will involve a binary join- just to the opposite way, while adding `, by = .EACHI` and specifying your desired function

```
setDT(df2)[df1, .(col2 = i.col2, col3 = sum(col2)), on = .(EndWith = col1), by = .EACHI]
#    EndWith col2 col3
# 1:       A   10   30
# 2:       B   20   30
# 3:       C   30   70
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. that solution is really fast

Comment: @David Arenburg I liked your answer here because that question was duplicated ! you Rock

Answer (score 0):

Using the `fuzzyjoin` package, I think you can make this work. E.g.:

```
#install.packages("fuzzyjoin")
df1$col1regex <- paste0(df1$col1,"$")
regex_join(df2, df1, by=c(col1="col1regex"), mode="right")

#  col1.x col2.x col1.y col2.y col1regex
#1     DA     10      A     10        A$
#2     FB     30      B     20        B$
#3      C     40      C     30        C$
```